# don't work password reset .net mvc2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the controller code to recover the password but it does not work.
a new password is sent to the mail.

```
   public ActionResult RecuperarPassword() {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RecuperarPassword(String mail)
    {
        using (mensajeriaEntities4 bdmensajeria = new mensajeriaEntities4())
        {
            var i = (from p in bdmensajeria.usuario
                     where  p.mail ==mail
                     select p).FirstOrDefault();

            if (i != null)
            {
                String status = SendPassword(i.contraseña, i.mail, i.login);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Por favor revise su correo para iniciar sesión");

            }
            else {
               ModelState.AddModelError("", "Por favor ingrese un correo valido registrado");

            }

            return View();
        }
    }

    public String SendPassword(String contraseña, String mail, String login) {

        try
        {
            MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
            email.To.Add(mail);
            email.From = new MailAddress("ivesandrey@gmail.com");
            email.Subject = "Recuperar contraseña para su cuenta" + mail;
            String userMessage = "";

            userMessage = userMessage + "<br/><b> Login:</b>" + mail;
            userMessage = userMessage + "<br/><b> contraseña:>/b>" + contraseña;

            String Body = "Hola" + login + ",<br/><br/>Estos son sus datos de ingreso:<br/><br/>" + userMessage + "<br/><br/>Gracias";
            email.Body = Body;
            email.IsBodyHtml = true;


            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP Server Address of gmail
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ivvesandrey@gmail.com", "contraseña");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(email);
            return "Por favor verifique su correo para recuperar su contraseña";
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Error";
    }


    }
```

and the code of the view:

```
<script>
function Validate() {
    var data = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    if (data == "") {
        alert("Por favor ingrese su email.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Forgotpassword"))
{
<div>
    Recuperar Password:@Html.TextBox("mail", "", new { @style =              "width:200px;", @id = "txtEmail" })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript: return Validate();"
```

the submit button is not working, when I enter an invalid invalid email.
when i entered an email that is the database the page is still running and  does not send the mail.

Comment: Change form method to POST

Answer (score 1):

In your controller code the action is

```
RecuperarPassword(String mail)
```

But in your form the action is `Index` on the `Forgotpassword` controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Forgotpassword"))
```

They need to be the same - doesn't matter which one

Comment: I already made the change but it still does not work.                                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RecuperarPassword"))

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Html.BeginForm("Index", "Forgotpassword")
```

Would mean you are trying to call the `Index` method of the `ForgotPassword` controller. Your example doesn't have and `Index` method.

Given your example, this should get your method to fire assuming you supply the controller name:

```
Html.BeginForm("RecuperarPassword", "YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME")
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_12)